# How to split a string into a list, taking negative numbers into account?

Tags: python, string, split

I want to split a string like:

```
strg = "22+11-aa+bb-44-"
```

into a list like this:

```
my_list = ['22', '+','11', '-', 'aa', '+', 'bb', '-44', '-']
```

All the non-digit elements are totally split out, if the element after '-' is made of digits, then it should join together with the '-' and become a negative number.

Comment: Is there some reason `11` isn't in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution without regexs that makes it longer, but faster on the large data sets:

```
strg="22+11-aa+bb-44-"
arr=[]
i=0
for j in range(len(strg)):
        if strg[j] in '+-':
            arr.append(strg[i:j])
            if strg[j]=='-' and strg[min(j+1,len(strg)-1)].isdigit():
                i=j
            else:
                arr.append(strg[j])
                i=j+1
print arr
```

result:

```
['22', '+', '11', '-', 'aa', '+', 'bb', '-44', '-']
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import re

strg = "22+11-aa+bb-44+-zz99+-33-" 
print re.findall(r'-?\d+|[a-z]+|\W+?', strg)
```

result:

```
['22', '+', '11', '-', 'aa', '+', 'bb', '-44', '+', '-', 'zz', '99', '+', '-33', '-']
```